# Get elements of Array in order specified through seed

Tags: php, html, arrays, element

I'm currently trying to write a PHP script that will write out 3 array elements at a time. But the order should be generated by using a seed. So for example if the Array contains the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 and I use the seed 47395745894375 it should output the elements like 2,5,4. And if I put in another seed it should output the elements in a different order.
I hope you can help me with that

Comment: Please include your coding attempt.

Comment: And also the output should be in this format right - 5, 3, 4 as at position 4 we have 5, at position 7 % arr.length = 2 we have 3 and at position 3 we have 4 ... right  ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried and tell us what is not working